# Pass variable in Jenkinsfile over steps

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins file that have many steps.

This is my issue:

1) I want to run ansible playbook and keep a var in Jenkins run (like environment variable or something)

2) I want to run ANOTHER playbook in different step and USE that var.

example:

```
pipeline {
stages {
    stage('run ansible play1') {
        steps {
                dir("${WORKSPACE}") {
                    ansiblePlaybook([
                            inventory   : 'hosts',
                            playbook    : 'playbook1.yml',
                            installation: 'ansible',
                            colorized   : true,
                            extraVars   : [
                                    var1: "blah1",
                                    var2: "blah2",
                            ]
                    ])
                }
            }
        }
    }

    stage('run ansible play2') {
        steps {
                dir("${WORKSPACE}") {
                    ansiblePlaybook([
                            inventory   : 'hosts',
                            playbook    : 'playbook2.yml',
                            installation: 'ansible',
                            colorized   : true,
                            extraVars   : [
                                    var_from_last_play: "some_value",
                                ]
                        ])
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope i make myself clear... Thanks for your help and if you need more info tell me.

Answer (score 3):

on Jenkins pipelines you can declare environment variables at the top of the script like this:

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    MY_ENV_VAR='something' // Added variable
  }
  stages {
    stage('run ansible play1') {
      steps {
        dir("${WORKSPACE}") {
          ansiblePlaybook([
            inventory   : 'hosts',
            playbook    : 'playbook1.yml',
            installation: 'ansible',
            colorized   : true,
            extraVars   : [
              var1: "blah1",
              var2: "blah2",
            ]
          ])
          // you can also assign new value to the env 
          // variable depending on results of the script execution
          // env.MY_ENV_VAR = 'something'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('run ansible play2') {
      steps {
        dir("${WORKSPACE}") {
          ansiblePlaybook([
            inventory   : 'hosts',
            playbook    : 'playbook2.yml',
            installation: 'ansible',
            colorized   : true,
            extraVars   : [
              var_from_last_play: env.MY_ENV_VAR,
            ]
          ])
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way, you can get the variable at any stage you want, also you can set it to a desired value at the stage before (output from script or whatever)

Another way is to declare a global variable at the top outsite the 'pipeline {...}' tag as a Groovy 'def' and do the same but it is not as clean as the other solution

```
def myVar = ''
pipeline {
  ...
}
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted

Comment: CMassa thanks. I know that I can assign vars in "environment", but how will I assign "MY_ENV_VAR='something'" from the Ansible playbook? let's say how will I "return MY_ENV_VAR"?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, what you want to do is quite hard, but I guess you could do a trick with one of the following things:     

1-Stop using the plugin and execute ansible-playbook from command line with sh printing a debug message from the playbook and redirect output (to file for example), grep for the known environment variable then assign it to the jenkins pipeline environment and use it as normal.

2-Use the plugin doing the same as the other method but searching the Jenkins execution output

Comment: Thanks CMassa, but I want to stay with the plugin. the other idea I'll think about it because I don't want to search stuff on the Jenkins output.. I think that i have 2 choices, one is to try and get return value from the Ansible playbook if it was a success, a string value in my case, but i don't know 100 percent if Ansible support that I'll try that. the other idea that I have in mind is to assign environment variable in run (Ansible environment variable, then load), I did try that but no success. I couldn't assign the var to Jenkins run.. he wouldn't assign the var to Jenkins var...